# How to uncheck (deselect) checkbox in a datatable column programmatically?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having doubts with how can I enable/disable a checkbox programmatically in primefaces.
I wanna control the enable/disable status of the column checkbox by java code, if it's possible.
Someone could help me?

This is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="some" value="#{someManager.someDataModel}"  
                     selection="#{someManager.chooseSomethings}">

            <p:column binding="#{someManager.columnCheckBox}" selectionMode="multiple"/>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{some.nameOfTheSomething}"/>
            </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>
```

When I click in the datatable's checkbox, the selected data will show in the datatable below:

```
<p:dataList id="selectedDataList"
         value="#{someManager.chooseSomethings}" 
         var="c" rowIndexVar="i">
           <h:outputText id="choseSomeElement" value="#{c.nameOfTheSomething}"/>
           <p:commandLink value="x" process="@this" update=":form:selectedDataList" actionListener="#{userManager.remove}"/>
</p:dataList>
```

In this selection list, I can remove any element clicking in the "X" commandLink. This commandLink removes the data from the chooseSomethings List. When it's happen, I want to deselect(disable) again the checkbox of the corespondent element in the datatable (Restore the initial state).

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean to enable/disable the checkbox as in `<input type="checkbox" disabled="true">`, or do you actually mean to check/uncheck the checkbox as in `<input type="checkbox" checked="true">`? Checking/unchecking is after all much simpler achieved.

Comment: I modified my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I want to uncheck the checkbox programmatically. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primefaces synchronized both lists. 
When you remove the data from the chooseSomethings, the datatable will show the checkbox unchecked.
In this case you just put the datatable's id in the update attribute of the dataList.
Like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="some" value="#{someManager.someDataModel}"  
                 selection="#{someManager.chooseSomethings}">

        <p:column binding="#{someManager.columnCheckBox}" selectionMode="multiple"/>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{some.nameOfTheSomething}"/>
        </p:column> 
    </p:dataTable> 

<p:dataList id="selectedDataList"
     value="#{someManager.chooseSomethings}" 
     var="c" rowIndexVar="i">
       <h:outputText id="choseSomeElement" value="#{c.nameOfTheSomething}"/>
       <p:commandLink value="x" process="@this" update=":form:selectedDataList,:form:table" actionListener="#{userManager.remove}"/>
```